# Why do I get a segmentation fault depending on the inclusion order of my headers?

Tags: c++

I have the following file, which is part of a larger (but still small) program. The program compiles regardless of header inclusion order but it seg faults if I include `<fstream>` after my local files; if I include it before my local header files, the program runs fine.

```
#include <fstream>
#include "Bitmap.h"
#include "BitmapInfoHeader.h"
#include "BitmapFileHeader.h"

namespace bmap
{

Bitmap::Bitmap(int width, int height) : _width(width), _height(height), _pixels(new uint8_t[width * height * 3]{}) { }

void Bitmap::set_pixel(int x, int y, uint8_t red, uint8_t blue, uint8_t green) { }

bool Bitmap::write(string filename)
{
  BitmapFileHeader file_header;
  BitmapInfoHeader info_header;

  file_header.file_size = sizeof(BitmapInfoHeader) + sizeof(BitmapFileHeader) + _width * _height * 3;
  file_header.data_offset = sizeof(BitmapInfoHeader) + sizeof(BitmapFileHeader);

  info_header.width = _width;
  info_header.height = _height;

  std::ofstream outfile(filename, ios::out | ios::binary);
  if(!outfile) { return false; }
  outfile.write((char *)(&file_header), sizeof(file_header));
  outfile.write((char *)(&info_header), sizeof(info_header));
  outfile.write((char *)(_pixels.get()), _width * _height * 3);
  outfile.close();
  return true;
}

Bitmap::~Bitmap() { }

}
```

The header files included in the file above are shown below.

Bitmap.h:

```
#ifndef BITMAP_H_
#define BITMAP_H_

#include <cstdint>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

namespace bmap{

class Bitmap
{
 private:
  int _width{0};
  int _height{0};
  unique_ptr<uint8_t[]> _pixels{nullptr};

 public:
  Bitmap(int width, int height);
  bool write(string filename);
  void set_pixel(int x, int y, uint8_t red, uint8_t blue, uint8_t green);
  virtual ~Bitmap();
};
}

#endif
```

BitmapFileHeader.h:

```
#ifndef BITMAPFILEHEADER_H_
#define BITMAPFILEHEADER_H_

#include <cstdint>

namespace bmap
{

#pragma pack(2)
struct BitmapFileHeader
{
  char header[2]{ 'B', 'M' };
  int32_t file_size;
  int32_t reserved{0};
  int32_t data_offset;
};
}

#endif
```

BitmapInfoHeader.h:

```
#ifndef BITMAPINFOHEADER_H_
#define BITMAPINFOHEADER_H_

#include <cstdint>

namespace bmap
{

#pragma pack(2)
  struct BitmapInfoHeader
  {
    int32_t header_size{40};
    int32_t width;
    int32_t height;
    int16_t planes{1};
    int16_t bits_per_pixel{24};
    int32_t compression{0};
    int32_t data_size{0};
    int32_t horizontal_resolution{2400};
    int32_t vertical_resolution{2400};
    int32_t colors{0};
    int32_t important_colors{0};
  };
}
#endif
```

I thought it might be some dependency between header files but there doesn't seem to be.  I have also tried renaming the `Bitmap::write` method because I thought it might be clashing with the write method in `<fstream>` somehow, but that didn't change anything.  Any ideas?

GDB gives the following info:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007fff994bdf24 in std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::flush() () from /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
(gdb) where
#0  0x00007fff994bdf24 in std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::flush() () from /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
#1  0x00007fff994c299e in std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::sentry::sentry(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) () from /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
#2  0x00007fff994c41a6 in std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::write(char const*, long) () from /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
#3  0x0000000100001626 in bmap::Bitmap::write (this=0x7fff5fbffa50, filename=...) at Bitmap.cpp:26
#4  0x0000000100004d48 in main () at Mandelbrot.cpp:11
(gdb)
```

Comment: This is C++, not C

Comment: Undefined behavior most probably.

Comment: Generally that is a sign of undefined behavior in the code.

Comment: You forgot to set packing back to default: `#pragma pack ()`

Comment: Thanks to everyone, especially @RustyX, I didn't know I had to set packing back to default.